# Debian stable pinning

Tags: debian, apt

Is the following configuration correct for keeping debian stable version even after update/dist-upgrade? I made this for having backports enabled so that install some packages as "wine" that I need latest version, and I think that have to comment out the backports for `dist-upgrade`. Are these the correct way as I don't want to break my Debian?

1. My `/apt/apt.conf` is:

   ```
   APT::Default-Release "stable";
   ```
2. My `/apt/preferences` is:

   ```
   Package: *
   Pin: release I=Debian-Security
   Pin-Priority: 1001

   Package: *
   Pin: release a=stable
   Pin-Priority: 990

   Package: *
   Pin: release a=stable-updates
   Pin-Priority: 990

   Package: *
   Pin: release a=jessie-backports
   Pin-Priority: 675
   ```

Comment: I simply did away with the backports in the test servers I have with Stretch; all backporteds packages were correctly upgraded except libssl, php5 and the kernel itself

Comment: @maulinglawns code under enumerations requires 8 spaces

Comment: @Anthon Thank you! I wondered why I couldn't format properly, now I know!

Answer (score 3):

The backports repositories are already [configured](ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/Release) so that they're safe to use without pinning:

```
NotAutomatic: yes
ButAutomaticUpgrades: yes
```

This means that backported packages are *never* considered for automatic installation, nor are they valid candidates for upgrades from stable versions. But once you have installed a backported version of a package, you will get backported upgrades for that package automatically.

The pinning setup you have defined behaves in the same way as the default setup, except that security updates will always take priority, even if that entails downgrading a package.